# Align label and inputs vertical

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.group {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.small {
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="group">
    <label>From</label>
    <input>
    <input class="small">
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label>To</label>
    <input>
    <input class="small">
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I align this so that it looks like this:

[image]

At the moment, the first label is longer than the second and it's not aligned correctly. How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: give label to width

Comment: here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/caos4owz/

Comment: @chirag You mean, give width to label? :-P

Comment: yes width to label:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a fixed width to label:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.group {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.small {
  width: 60px;
}

label{
  width: 60px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="group">
    <label>From</label>
    <input>
    <input class="small">
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label>To</label>
    <input>
    <input class="small">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a fixed width to label:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.group {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.small {
  width: 60px;
}

label{
  width: 60px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will be enough instead of that

```css
.small {
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td><label>From</label></td>
<td> <input> <input class="small"></td>
<tr>
<td> <label>To</label></td>
<td>  <input> <input class="small"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```